# Comparing typeid pointers

Tags: c++

In this program I use typeid to check the derived type of an object:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

struct  Wrap
{
    explicit Wrap(int64_t id) : mImpl(new Impl<int64_t>(id)) {}

    explicit Wrap(std::string id) : mImpl(new Impl<std::string>(std::move(id))) {}    

    bool isInt64() const
    {
        const ImplBase& impl = *mImpl;
        return (&typeid(impl) == &typeid(const Impl<int64_t>));
    }    

    bool isString() const
    {
        const ImplBase& impl = *mImpl;
        return &typeid(impl) == &typeid(const Impl<std::string>);
    }

private:
    struct ImplBase
    {
        virtual ~ImplBase() {}
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Impl : ImplBase
    {
        Impl(T value) :
            mValue(std::move(value))
        {
        }

        T mValue;
    };

    std::shared_ptr<const ImplBase> mImpl;
};

int main()
{
    Wrap r1(int64_t(1));
    assert(r1.isInt64());

    Wrap r2(std::string("s"));
    assert(r2.isString());
}
```

It seems to work, however, I worry that this may not work on all platforms. Also I'm not sure if I should use:

```
typeid(const Impl<std::string>&) // with ref
```

instead of

```
typeid(const Impl<std::string>) // without ref
```

in the comparison functions.

Is the above code correct? If not, then how can I fix it?

Comment: Why would the typeid field in the VT store the reference type ?

Comment: @Arunmu good point, I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `typeid`, it can be applied to either an expression or a type. When applied to a type, as you have:

> Refers to a std::type_info object representing the type type. If type
>   is a reference type, the result refers to a std::type_info object
>   representing the referenced type.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid. So it does not make any difference whether or not you use the reference. The same source goes on to say:

> There is no guarantee that the same std::type_info instance will be referred to by all evaluations of the typeid expression on the same
>   type, although std::type_info::hash_code of those type_info objects
>   would be identical, as would be their std::type_index.

That means that comparing `&typeid(impl)` to something else, could return false even when the object has the same dynamic type. So it's not such a good choice to compare their addresses. You should compare the objects themselves directly instead, i.e. just remove the `&` operator from both sides, because `std::type_info` (returned by `typeid`) has `operator==` defined.